# Clasp can not create a new Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

I had cloned an app script with this terminal command

```
clasp clone <scriptId>
```

to this folder:

> .../desktop/AppsScriptProjects

and the files were downloaded to the folder

> .../desktop/AppsScriptProjects/AppsScriptName

but now, I want to create a new Apps Script.

I navigated back to:

> .../desktop/AppsScriptProjects

and executed:

```
clasp create "Test Project"
```

but I got the error:

> Nested clasp projects are not supported.

What am I doing wrong?

> Version Info:
>
> OS: Mac Os (Mojave)
>
> Node: v10.15.3
>
> Clasp: 2.1.0

When I run `ls -a` on the directory that I intend to create a new apps script and all I got was :

> . ..

Comment: What's the output of `ls -a` for the folder you executed the command in? Also when using "3rd party" plugins that are under active development it is very important to include the version information.

Comment: it has been included

Comment: How can you get only `. ..` if you cloned the project `AppsScriptName` there already? You should have that folder as a subdirectory.

Comment: in the cloned project directory, i have the list of files in the apps script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `clasp create <words>` [creates a project *in the current directory*](https://github.com/google/clasp#create), with the script project name `<words>`, and no files other than `appsscript.json` and `.clasp.json`.

**Even when given a `--rootDir <folder name>` argument**, the project is created *in the current directory*. This is the same behavior as `clasp clone`, in that the clone is performed *to the current directory*.

So:

```
$ cd ~/clasp_projects
$ clasp create "project 1"
Clone which script? (Use arrow keys)
Clone which script? standalone
Created new standalone script <...>
$ ls -a
./ ../ .clasp.json appsscript.json
```

If you had instead supplied a root directory too:

```
$ cd ~/clasp_projects
$ mkdir "project 1"
$ clasp create "project 1" --rootDir "project 1"
Clone which script? (Use arrow keys)
Clone which script? standalone
Created new standalone script <...>
$ ls -a
./ ../ .clasp.json appsscript.json 'project 1'/
$ ls -a "project 1"
./ ../
```

not much would be different.

For both cases, your current directory would now have a `.clasp.json` file, indicating to clasp that this is a clasp-associated repo and corresponds to a single Apps Script project. In your case, you have the following directory structure:

```
AppsScriptProjects/
`--- AppsScriptName/
     |--- .clasp.json
     |--- appsscript.json
     |--- myscript.js
       ...
```

When you attempt to invoke `clasp create "Test Project"` from `AppsScriptProjects/`, you are telling clasp to create this structure:

```
AppsScriptProjects/
|--- AppsScriptName/
|    |--- .clasp.json
|    |--- appsscript.json
|    |--- myscript.js
|      ...
|--- .clasp.json
`--- appsscript.json
```

#### Solution

Instead of the above approaches, create & cd into `"Test Project/"`:

```
$ cd AppsScriptProjects
$ mkdir "Test Project"
$ cd "Test Project"
$ clasp create
...
```

which will then yield

```
AppsScriptProjects/
|--- AppsScriptName/
|    |--- .clasp.json
|    |--- appsscript.json
|    |--- myscript.js
|      ...
`--- Test Project/
     |--- .clasp.json 
     `--- appsscript.json
```

In short: `clasp` works with your current directory. It does not create projects in child directories. While it can create project *files* in child directories, the **project directory** (in which you can find `.clasp.json`) is the directory in which you invoked `clasp`.

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it. but seem you forgot to do `cd "project 1"`

Comment: @micklo is that not what I say to do in the latter part of the answer, re: `"Test Project"`? The first and second are examples of calling it from the parent directory, and of doing that but with `rootDir` given. Anyway, glad you got it sorted.

Comment: oops  oversight. Thanks again

Comment: That would be great! 