# Clasp won't clone Google Drive project - Error: clasp.json already exists

Tags: google-drive-api, clasp

Clasp version

```
$ clasp -v
2.4.1
```

Setup information used: [clasp - The Apps Script CLI](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/clasp/#0)

Test setup:

1. Created testClasp project in `https://script.google.com/home/`
2. Navigated to local dir `~\Google Drive\Technical-local\gDriveDev`
3. Use `clasp login` to login to Google account from local dir
4. clasp clone ID  creates error (clasp.json already exists)

I note that the local dir has:

```
-a---           6/09/2022  1:57 pm             89 .clasp.json
```

At some stage, while trying to clone a project, this file was created. And for some reason this is preventing the cloning process.

I have searched this problem:
In this post [Clasp can not create a new Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55431729/clasp-can-not-create-a-new-apps-script) the following phrase caught my attention "*For both cases, your current directory would now have a .clasp.json file, indicating to clasp that this is a clasp-associated repo and corresponds to a single Apps Script project.*"

So I go back in my path and create a new folder eg ~\Google Drive\Technical-local\test

I login using `clasp login`

```
Authorization successful.
Default credentials saved to: C:\Users\david\.clasprc.json
```

I invoke the clone instruction:

```
clasp clone ID "11nv2X-WTo4NEVVu6fge8RZIqflLEEfIy9WRt9NOdjV7k9DVoO8_rqDYZ"
Could not find script.
Did you provide the correct scriptId?
Are you logged in to the correct account with the script?
```

I would answer absolutely yes to the last two questions. But have no answers to not being able to clone with clasp.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at (https://github.com/google/clasp/), help in use clasp.
Delete the generated files .clasp.json and appscript.json and remove the call "ID" word:
ex.:

`clasp login`

`clasp clone <number id>`